# Trying to set FileChooserUI for the UIManager

Tags: java, look-and-feel, jcomponent, uimanager

I'm trying to set the look and feel for a single class (the JFileChooser speciifcally) because I need to do some custom things to it, and have the rest of the JComponents assume the default look and feel.

The problem is that when I attempt to set the FileChooserUI (which is the UI class ID returned from `JFileChooser#getUIClassId()` that is used by JFileChooser to determine the look and feel to use) in the UIManager, I still end up with the default look and feel for the JFileChooser. Here is what I have tried:

```
UIManager.put("FileChooserUI", MyCustomFileChooserUI.class.getName());
System.out.println("Before JFileChooserCreation using static text: " + UIManager.get("FileChooserUI"));
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.showDialog(null, "foo");
System.out.println("After JFileChooser creation using JFileChooser#getUIClassID(): " + UIManager.get(fc.getUIClassID()));
System.out.println("actual UI: " + fc.getUI().getClass().getName());
```

The results from that attempt print out the following:

```
Before JFileChooserCreation using static text: classpath.to.MyCustomFileChooserUI
After JFileChooser creation using JFileChooser#getUIClassID(): classpath.to.MyCustomFileChooserUI
actual ComponentUI: javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI
```

The JFileChooser figures out what look and feel to use by asking the UIManager what class to instantiate from its own call to getUIClassID, which is what I have set in the UIManager to use my own custom look and feel for JFileChooser. Somehow, it is still trying to use the MetalFileChooserUI instead of my custom class. Does anyone have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

I know I can do `MyCustomFileChooserUI#installUI(Jcomponent)`, but the reason I can't do this involves the fact that the JFileChooser does not  overwrite the old reference to the old ComponentUI object after you do this, which creates issues in which the new look and feel does not function properly. So this is not a valid solution for me.